12V through USB Type C without PD
Can I get 12V to my system through USB type C without PD or configuration CC lines or Using CC controller?
If yes how can I do that .

How much current?

5 V -> 12 V boost converter.

No, if you use the CC resistors it defines current at 5V, if you want anything but 5V (up to 15W), you need a USB PD controller.

http://kevinzhengwork.blogspot.com/2014/09/usb-type-c-configuration-channel-cc-pin.html

I'm sure you could connect an off-the-shelf 12V power supply to the GND and VBUS pins on a USB C socket if you really wanted to, and it would power a 12V device.
Just make sure you never connect anything else.  Without any of the PD circuitry, it would fry any device that expects 5V or 9V.

Came here to say the same - this applies especially if you're designing the thing with the port. Within reason, a connector can be used to output whatever you want (obviously, high voltage/power needs thought to safety and arcing between close pins). Just make sure it's very clearly marked, and reserve it for things that unaware people can't use (i.e. you don't want your partner plugging in their £1,000 phone into a non-standard USB-C port and nuking it).
